# Boost - deserialize an array only when sizes match

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization, stdarray

I'd like deserialization to fail when size of the array that I'm trying to deserialize to does not match the originally serialized array's size.

So far it only fails when `arr1_size > arr2_size` and I want it to be `arr1_size != arr2_size`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

int main()
{
    const size_t arr1_size = 4, arr2_size = 3;
    std::stringstream ss;

    // save
    std::array<int, arr1_size> arr1;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(ss, boost::archive::no_header);
    oar & arr1;

    // load
    std::array<int, arr2_size> arr2;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ss, boost::archive::no_header);
    iar & arr2; // throw on size inequality, please
}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16dbf6095505567c)

---

I thought about:

- serializing through `std::vector`s and handling this myself, but that might lead to performance loss
- checking `arr2` afterwards (if it doesn't throw on `arr1_size > arr2_size`) for trailing default-constructed class type elements or otherwise special values) to handle `arr1_size < arr2_size`

Is there anything simpler, preferably provided by boost that I've missed?

Comment: I think you'll either have to serialise the size of the array prior to the array itself and then check it on deserialisation, or switch to a vector (how much performance loss are we really talking here?)

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks for the third way, the elements would be of type derived from `boost::bimap` - not movable, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/blob/develop/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp#L585) is the Boost code you want to bypass, specifically this test is insufficient:

```
    if(static_cast<std::size_t>(count) > current_count)
        boost::serialization::throw_exception(
            archive::archive_exception(
                boost::archive::archive_exception::array_size_too_short
            )
        );
```

One workaround is to substitute your own serialization for `std::array`. This is easiest if you can avoid including the header `boost/serialization/array.hpp` for any translation unit that you serialize `std::array`. It is still possible if you need that header file (e.g. to serialize ordinary arrays) - the trick to avoid matching the [Boost templated function](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/blob/develop/include/boost/serialization/array.hpp#L139):

```
template <class Archive, class T, std::size_t N>
void serialize(Archive& ar, std::array<T,N>& a, const unsigned int /* version */)
...
```

One way to do this is to explicitly specify your element type:

```
typedef int MyArrayElementType;

namespace std {
   template<class Archive, size_t N>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, std::array<MyArrayElementType, N>& a, const unsigned int version)
   ...
```

Here's an adaptation of your MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

// Supply your element type here.
typedef int MyArrayElementType;

namespace std {
   template<class Archive, size_t N>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, std::array<MyArrayElementType, N>& a, const unsigned int version) {
      boost::serialization::split_free(ar, a, version);
   }

   template<class Archive, size_t N>
   void save(Archive& ar, const std::array<MyArrayElementType, N>& a, const unsigned int version) {
      // Adapted code from oserializer.hpp save_array_type::invoke().
      boost::serialization::collection_size_type count(N);
      ar << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);
      ar << boost::serialization::make_array(static_cast<MyArrayElementType const*>(&a[0]), count);
   }

   template<class Archive, size_t N>
   void load(Archive& ar, std::array<MyArrayElementType, N>& a, const unsigned int version) {
      // Adapted code from iserializer.hpp load_array_type::invoke().
      boost::serialization::collection_size_type count;
      ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);
      if(static_cast<std::size_t>(count) != N)
         boost::serialization::throw_exception(
            std::runtime_error("std::array size mismatch")
            );
      ar >> boost::serialization::make_array(static_cast<MyArrayElementType*>(&a[0]), count);
   }
}

int main()
{
    const size_t arr1_size = 3, arr2_size = 4;
    std::stringstream ss;

    // save
    std::array<int, arr1_size> arr1;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(ss, boost::archive::no_header);
    oar & arr1;

    // load
    std::array<int, arr2_size> arr2;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ss, boost::archive::no_header);
    iar & arr2; // throw on size inequality, please
}
```

[Live on CoLiRu](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cf407b56b727a69)

This uses the same array serialization machinery that the built-in serialization does, so it should have exactly the same performance. If you are able to remove `boost/serialization/array.hpp` you could change `MyArrayElementType` to a template argument instead.

Comment: Cool, but isn't adding those function templates to `std` namespace UB? I could live without using `operator&` on that and being more explicit.

Comment: You are correct that adding `std` functions is officially undefined behavior, though I think this works widely. If you prefer you can explicitly call `load()` and `save()` with a namespace of your choosing.